# Bootstrap mobile navbar link goto URL instead toogle

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I have a bootstrap navbar links that open sub menus on hover and goto `href` when click. Thats perfect. The problem is when it comes to a mobile navbar. These links becomes a toggle button and doesn't go to `href` link. I need them to goto href when click and toggle only when click to the caret.

The navbar can be seen [here](http://test.odontologosmalca.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your document.ready

```
$(".nav").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    var target = $(event.target)
    if (target.is("a"))
        window.location.replace(target.attr("href"));
})
```

Comment: Thank you @potatopeelings it works but now the link doesn't drop down the submenu links. Is it possible to make the text get the url and the caret open the submenu on click?

Comment: Its doing that already. Just press on the caret - its pretty small, so you have to either have thin fingers or css style the caret bigger :-) personally, i think its not good ux - reusing the same item for open and navigate, esp because some people think the click will just open the submenu if there is one.

Comment: Thank you again @potatopeelings, you are right! It is working. I think the menu should be quite efficient if the caret is moved to the right and change it for a big arrow icon pointing down. To make it work like a bootstrap navbar button with bullet. Do you know what I mean?  Any suggestion to get this done?

Comment: The rest of the work sould be just CSS coding, right?

Comment: Yep, just CSS - you already have an element there, just have to style it. You can probably also have a small separator between this icon and the rest of the menu item - kind of like a border.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm googling right now =) - How to change the caret for an icon, and how to insert a separator line beside. I have no clue so far =(

Comment: I think something like display: inline-block; float: right; and width: 10% or a set number of pixels on the caret selector should do it. Your test page is offline now?

Comment: thank you so much for keeping in to this. I'm coming back to work after being sick for thwo days. Yes, the demo is online. I will apply your CSS suggestion and let you know.